# How to create new array based off data from another one

Tags: python

Say I have an array:

`a = [10,12,0],[11,54,1],[17,34,1],[65,98,0]`

How would i create a new array excluding the rows with a 0 in the 3rd column?

ie so the new array would be:

`b = [11,54], [17,34]`

Comment: `b = [x[:2] for x in a if x[2] != 0]`

Comment: For now `a` isn't a list, but a tuple of 4 lists

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ([10,12,0], [11,54,1], [17,34,1], [65,98,0])
b = tuple([e[:-1] for e in a if e[-1]])
```

output

```
([11, 54], [17, 34])
```

Comment: Hi!! thanks so much for your reply but how would you make it so that b was a complete 2x2 matrice?

Answer (score 0):

As @rdas already commented, to get a new list based on your specified condition, you can use list comprehension:

```
b = [row[:2] for row in a if row[2] != 0]
```

Be aware that type of `b` is a `list`, not a `tuple` as `a` in your example. You can also just convert to `tuple` afterwards with `b = tuple(b)`.

When you are working with vectors a lot, you should seriously consider using numpy.

Comment: Hi!! thanks so much for your reply but how would you make it so that b was a complete 2x2 matrice?

Comment: Python does not have `matrix` dtype. So I am not sure what are you asking. You can use `numpy` as I said earlier: `import numpy as np` and `b = np.array(b)`. The shape of the array will depend on `a`. So it can end up as bigger array than 2x2.